# Android Device Admin not recognizing wrong fingerprint

Tags: android, fingerprint, device-admin

My app is acting as device admin and recognizing wrong pin,password,pattern. And in such cases it taking picture and uploading to server. But when i tried with wrong fingerprint, its not recognizing wrong fingerprint. Can anyone help ?